# Is it possible to take a screenshot at Chromium, Chrome without using a headless instance or an extension?

Tags: javascript, screenshot, chromium, screen-capture

It is possible to take a screenshot using extension code at Chromium, Chrome 59+. At Firefox an extension is not necessary to take a screenshot of the screen or an open application window. Is it possible to take a screenshot of the current browser screen at Chromium, Chrome  programmatically using JavaScript and without using extension code?

Comment: The only way I could think of would be with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{'mediaSource':'window'}})` but only FF allows this for non chrome: scripts.

Comment: @Kaiido Then the answer to the question is that the requirement is not currently possible programmatically outside of extension code?

Comment: At least **I** don't know any way to take a screenshot from web-js in current chromium browser no

Comment: @Kaiido is right